# Представить коллекцию объектов в виде таблицы в property grid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

у меня есть коллекция объектов, в объекте поле логического типа.

```
puplic class Column
{
    public bool IsVisible{ get; set; }

    private string Name{ set; }

    public Column(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Мне необходимо коллекцию объектов в PropertyGrid представить в виде таблицы.
Например, есть набор столбцов таблицы и флаг его видимости.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как реализовать такую штуку. Может быть тут можно применить TypeConverter?

Comment: Создаете  для коллекции отдельный класс и вешаете на него TypeConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю взять `DataGridView` вместо `PropertyGrid`.

Класс модели колонки:

```
public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Создаём список колонок:

```
var list = new List<Column>
{
    new Column { Name = "Фамилия",  IsVisible  = true },
    new Column { Name = "Имя",      IsVisible  = true },
    new Column { Name = "Отчество", IsVisible  = false },
    new Column { Name = "Возраст",  IsVisible  = true },
    new Column { Name = "Город",    IsVisible  = false },
};
```

Привязываем список к датагриду:

```
var dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
dataGridView.DataSource = list;
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как раз так и сделала. Спасибо за ответ)